# Is there any performance difference between using VMware image compared to installing the ISO file?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

Many operating systems have the option of downloading the VMware image so there would be no need of installing the O.S in VMware

but my question is, is there any cons in doing this compared to installing the ISO file? for example will there be a performance penalty for it? or any other penalty?

other than saving time, what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, there *should* be no difference other than saving time.

There are, however, a couple of caveats:

- This is only generally true if you end up using the default storage configuration, both in the OS and in VMWare.  If either configuration needs to be different for your usage, the pre-built image may actually take *longer* to set up than just doing a clean install.
- Some OS's that offer such images also have them pre-tuned to have optimal settings for the VM software the image is for.  For example, most pre-built VM images have the default user account already configured to allow access to whatever filesharing the hypervisor provides, and may have configuration to allow this by default for newly created users.
- In certain cases, you may need to do some special modifications to the install ISO to get it to work properly in the VM.  The classic example of this is Windows on QEMU with VirtIO drivers (you have to modify the regular Windows installation ISO to include VirtIO drivers to even get the ISO to boot correctly).  This is thankfully rare for most operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

There are no differences, except that as you don't control the creation,
there might exist future problems.

For example, the disk might have been created with a hard disk that is too
small and not growable, packages you need are missing and conflicting packages
installed, settings that you don't know were setup for you etc. or even
malware was installed with/without intention.

There isn't really an answer. For myself, unless this is for a one-time test,
I prefer creating my own virtual machines.